# ASIHTTPRequest don't save pdf file when the delegate set

Tags: ios, pdf, delegates, asihttprequest

I try to download a pdf from server and this is my code

```
ASIHTTPRequest *req = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[GlobalMethod convertURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SITE_IMAGE_URL,pview.nameLable.text]]]];
    NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    // Add your filename to the directory to create your saved pdf location
    NSString *pdfLocation = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];

    // TEMPORARY PDF PATH
    // Get the Caches directory
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    // Add your filename to the directory to create your temp pdf location
    NSString *tempPdfLocation = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];

    req.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground = YES;
    req.delegate = self;
    req.downloadProgressDelegate = pview.progressView;
    [req setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
    [req setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
    [req setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pview.nameLable.text,REQ_FILE_NAME, nil]];
    [req setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempPdfLocation];
    [req setDownloadDestinationPath:pdfLocation];
    [req startAsynchronous];
```

it didn't save file to the destination path when the delegate set to self but it work correctly when I comment this line

```
req.delegate = self;
```

I really need the delegate to be set
what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and solve it. It's all happened because of a simple if else. In

> ASIHTTPRequest.m

in

> -(void)handleBytesAvailable

method you have this code in

```
// Does the delegate want to handle the data manually?
        if (dataWillBeHandledExternally) {

            NSData *data = nil;
            if ([self isResponseCompressed] && ![self shouldWaitToInflateCompressedResponses]) {
                data = inflatedData;
            } else {
                data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];
            }
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(passOnReceivedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];

        // Are we downloading to a file?
        }else if ([self downloadDestinationPath]) {
            BOOL append = NO;
            if (![self fileDownloadOutputStream]) {
                if (![self temporaryFileDownloadPath]) {
                    [self setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]]];
                } else if ([self allowResumeForFileDownloads] && [[self requestHeaders] objectForKey:@"Range"]) {
```

when you delete the else before the second if and change it to

```
// Does the delegate want to handle the data manually?
            if (dataWillBeHandledExternally) {

                NSData *data = nil;
                if ([self isResponseCompressed] && ![self shouldWaitToInflateCompressedResponses]) {
                    data = inflatedData;
                } else {
                    data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];
                }
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(passOnReceivedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];

            // Are we downloading to a file?
            }if ([self downloadDestinationPath]) {
                BOOL append = NO;
                if (![self fileDownloadOutputStream]) {
                    if (![self temporaryFileDownloadPath]) {
                        [self setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]]];
                    } else if ([self allowResumeForFileDownloads] && [[self requestHeaders] objectForKey:@"Range"]) {
```

it work correctly with delegate and also save to this